# Updating Publishers from CTurtle to Diamondback

Tags: ros, cturtle, ros-diamondback, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm in the process of migrating some other people's CTurtle code to Diamondback (while learning ROS at the same time), and I'd like to confirm some behaviour that I haven't seen documented.

In the CTurtle code, there are a lot of simple publishers that use std_msgs, such as:

```
stringPublisher_ = nodeHandle_.advertise<std_msgs::String>("/string", 1);
```

or

```
floatPublisher_ = nodeHandle_.advertise<std_msgs::Float32>("/float", 1);
```

When these are called however, it's not with a std_msgs:: data type, but instead the base data type, e.g.:

```
 std::string state = "IDLE"
 stringPublisher_.publish(state);
```

or

```
 floatPublisher_.publish((float)3.14);
```

This code worked fine under CTurtle, but now that I'm trying to port it to Diamondback it treats the std::string/float32 as a ROS message and as a result throws an error. Specifically:

```
 /ros-diamondback/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp_traits/include/ros/message_traits.h:121: error: request for member ‘__getMD5Sum’ in ‘m’, which is of non-class type ‘const float’
```

This is easily fixed by pushing the data into the message variable, for e.g.:

```
 std_msgs::String msgStr;
 msgStr.data = state;
 stringPublisher_.publish(msgStr);
```

But I'm just curious if this is an intended change or if I'm missing something?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9933/updating-publishers-from-cturtle-to-diamondback/) by [gammell](https://answers.ros.org/users/518/gammell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-05-10

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at the cturtle code path. I don't see any constructor for std_msgs::String for instance which should have allowed for the conversion. Nor can I see any code path for for publisher::publish that would allow it separately.

I would expect that the code you posted would *not* work in CTurtle either. I would go back and double check that it worked in the first place.

If it really does work, if you're using eclipse, follow the `publish` function, back to its declaration, and see which invocation it's calling. Or, follow `std_msgs::String`'s constructor back and see what constructor could possibly create a string message directly from a std::string.

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gammell](https://answers.ros.org/users/518/gammell/) on 2011-05-12**:
Ok. So I haven't tracked down how it *works* in CTurtle yet, but I know why it doesn't work in Diamondback. It's the ROS_ASSERT_MSG at line 111 of publisher.h that throws the error. Those ROS_ASSERT_MSG were not present in the publisher.h in CTurtle...

**Comment by [gammell](https://answers.ros.org/users/518/gammell/) on 2011-05-12**:
Eric, I agree that rospy is probably the reason someone wrote this code in the first place, but I can confirm that it absolutely does work in roscpp in CTurtle. I will see if I can track down the invocation or something similar.

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-05-11**:
I believe rospy can handle this situation, so perhaps this is just a case of confusion between features in rospy and roscpp.